# How to Calculate Interest Only Payment - Formula

Tags: mortgage, loans

I am trying to make a calculation for a monthly and biweekly - INTEREST ONLY.

My Values:
Loan: 30,000
Annual Rate: 2.99%
Term 2 Years, 4 Months

Calculation:
2 Years 4 Months = 2.33 Years
Monthly

```
Interest_Per_Year = 30,000 * ((2.99 / 100) * 2.33) / 2.33
Total Interest = Interest_Per_Year * (2 years + ( 4 Months / 12)
Monthly Payments = Total Interest / (2.33 * 12)
```

Bi Weekly

```
BiWeekly = (Interest Rate / 100) / 26
TotalInterest = BiWeekly * Number Of Months
ByWeeklyPay = totalInterest / Number Of Months

Total Bi Weekly Interest = totalInterest * 2


My Answers: 
Monthly: $74.95
Total: $2691

BiWeekly: $34.5
Total: $2484
```

Can someone please verify if this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 2.99% [effective annual rate of interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation).

```
s = 30000
i = 2.99/100
```

Here is the monthly interest calculation.

`r` is the periodic rate calculated from the effective annual rate.

The periodic interest is `s r` so the total interest is `s r n`.

```
n = 28
r = (1 + i)^(1/12) - 1
s r   = 73.7448
s r n = 2064.85
```

Here is the biweekly interest calculation, assuming [52.1775 weeks per year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).

```
b = 52.1775/2
n = 2 b + b/3
r = (1 + i)^(1/b) - 1
s r   = 33.8978
s r n = 2063.48
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bi-weekly "total interest" calculation is off: the 26 payments isn't relevant since you're not multiplying the interest per year by 4/26 for the final part year (it's still 4/12 of a year, regardless of how many payments you make). It's also missing a closing bracket.

The rest seems fine, but you can simplify:

- Interest per year    = loan * annual rate = $30,000 * 2.99%
- Monthly interest     = Interest per year / 12
- Fortnightly interest = Interest per year / 26
- Number of months     = 2*12 + 4 = 28
- Total interest       = Monthly interest * number of months

Comment: I have updated my question for the bi weekly, please see!